# Why do I see <%@ Page Title %> tag above content page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have deployed my website to my production server and the site opens.

However, it does not look the same as when deployed locally.

This is how it looks locally: 
[image]

And how it looks in production:
[image]

The local one has the navigation bar from the Site.master and everything is centered.  The production deployment has no background styling, everything is adjusted to the left and you can see a tag and its parameters directly rather than the navigation header.

I see two possibilities:

- it's a programmatic error that requires I code for Production differently than I code for Local or Test
- it's a server configuration issue (something isn't configured correctly or at all)

Why would I be seeing: `<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>` above the content of my page?

Comment: Can you use Developer Tools to confirm that all of your css files are download and there are no 404 errors?  It may be a pathing issue.

Comment: @Kevin Raffay I already cleared the 404 errors- had to add MIME types for .aspx and .master

.css files appear to all be in play.

It seems like it is loading the default page directly without loading it into the Site.master's content panel.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Console that might be causing the page not to render?  Also, can you view the page source and notice any malformed tags?

Comment: @Kevin Raffay I'm not getting anything in the console, however, when I turned off the default page and tried to go directly to the Site.master file I get the following: `This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.`  

The tag on line 1 is `<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>`

Leads me to believe it cannot handle the `<%@` tag

Comment: @wolfsshield Are there any other ASP.NET website(s) hosted on the server that are working fine? Please check you have required features installed on the server for rendering ASP.NET pages.

Comment: Yes, I agree w/@MohsinMehmood, make sure you have ASP.NET installed on that server

Comment: @MohsinMehmood From what I can see it is installed.  Whether it is configured correctly...I'm not sure yet.  This is the first website on the server.

Comment: This might help: https://forums.iis.net/t/1233497.aspx .   Did you take the opportunity to even do a simple search?  I literally copied and pasted your error into google and got this result.

Comment: @Jodast Yeah, I saw that. However, I didn't merely copy my files to the server.  I used the Visual Studio Publish feature in conjunction with IIS and Web Deploy as stated at the end of the solution proposed there.